# How can I pass certain params to generate my PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Question is I have a report that I send to a PDF I want to narrow down this report so I use two date pickers to pick a start date and end date to show reports for only for that range of dates. Now my PDF works great if don't include my params but, this will print everything and not just the data I want that falls in between my params [e] and [f]. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

[e] = startdate and [f] = end date

I want to be able to generate my PDF to only show data for the selected range of dates only, but for some reason I keep getting null.. Below I will explain each step I'm taking to try and work on achieving this.

So this is my controller with my PDF format.

```
class EntryController < ApplicationController

 def print_version
    yr = DateTime.now
    jan = yr.beginning_of_year
    dec = yr.end_of_year

    #####These are my params
    e = params[:e] #start date 
    f = params[:f] #end date

    @labor_ticketer = LaborTicket.where("user_id = ? and type = ? and setup_completed = ? and workorder_type = ? and transaction_date >= ? and transaction_date <= ?", 'TIMEOFF', 'I', 'N', 'W', jan, dec)

    @labor_ticket = @labor_ticketer.where(:transaction_date => e..f) #looks at start and end and finds all between e(start) and f(end) 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html #print_version.html.haml
      format.pdf do
        pdf = LaborTicketPdf.new(@labor_ticket, e, f)
        send_data pdf.render, filename: "laborticket.pdf",
                              type: "application/pdf",
                              disposition: "inline"
      end
    end
  end
```

******Side note!!!Sorry for the confusion on labor_ticketer and labor_ticket and LaborTicket they are all the same model which is called LaborTicket.

Here is my LaborTicketPdf.rb

```
class LaborTicketPdf < Prawn::Document


   def initialize(labor_ticket, e, f) #tried to initialize params [e] and [f] here didn't work...
     super(top_margin: 20)
     @labor_ticket = labor_ticket
     title
     main_build
   end

   def title
     text "Labor Ticket Report"
   end

   def main_build
     move_down 20
     table transaction_rows do
       row(0).font_style = :bold
       columns(1..3).align = :right
       self.row_colors = ["DDDDDD", "FFFFFF"]
       self.header = true
     end
   end

   def transaction_rows
      [["Employee ID", "Date transfered", "Transaction Date(Requested Dates)", "Indirect ID"]] +
      @labor_ticket.map do |l|
         [l.employee_id, l.clock_out.strftime('%m/%d/%y'), l.transaction_date.strftime('%m/%d/%y'), l.indirect_id]
      end
    end
  end
```

Bonus here is where I get my start[e] and end[f] params.

This is my print_version view

```
 %h2 Date Search
 = form_tag print_version_entry_index_path, method: :get do
   = text_field_tag :e, params[:e], :class => 'datepicker', :placeholder => "Date Search"
   = text_field_tag :f, params[:f], :class => 'datepicker', :placeholder => "Date Search"
   = submit_tag "Search Date", :class=> "btn btn-primary"
   = link_to "Clear Search", print_version_entry_index_path, :class => "btn btn-success"


 - 2.times do
   %br

 %p= link_to "Printable Report (PDF)", print_version_entry_index_path(@labor_ticket, format: "pdf")
```

more bonus here is the `sql` it is getting

```
  LaborTicket Load (6.4ms)  SELECT "LABOR_TICKET".* FROM "LABOR_TICKET"  

  WHERE (user_id = 'TIMEOFF' and type = 'I' and setup_completed = 'N' and workorder_type = 'W' and transaction_date >= TO_DATE('2015-01-01 04:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and transaction_date <= TO_DATE('2016-01-01 03:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))

  AND ("LABOR_TICKET"."TRANSACTION_DATE" BETWEEN NULL AND NULL) 
  ################################################^ its getting null for params [e]start and [f]end 

  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
  Sent data laborticket.pdf (7.3ms)
  Completed 200 OK in 619ms (Views: 6.8ms | ActiveRecord: 253.1ms)
```

Here is what my params look like when they do get passed in but, for some reason they dont want to be passed in when formating to PDF..

```
  LaborTicket Load (79.5ms)  SELECT "LABOR_TICKET".* FROM "LABOR_TICKET"  

  WHERE (user_id = 'TIMEOFF' and type = 'I' and setup_completed = 'N' and workorder_type = 'W' and transaction_date >= TO_DATE('2015-01-01 04:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and transaction_date <= TO_DATE('2016-01-01 03:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) 

  AND ("LABOR_TICKET"."TRANSACTION_DATE" BETWEEN TO_DATE('2015-06-01','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('2015-06-12','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))

  # start(param[e] = 2015-06-01','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS
  # end(param[f] = 2015-06-12','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS
```

Comment: What are the values of `params[:e]` and `params[:f]`?  You've missed out the log lines showing the parameters passed

Comment: ("LABOR_TICKET"."TRANSACTION_DATE" BETWEEN NULL AND NULL) both of these NULLS are my params [e] and [f]. I updated my question with what It looks like when my params are being passed but, for some reason I cant pass them when I generate my PDF they just return as NULL. @japed

Comment: Can you post your code for initialising datepicker?  It looks like maybe your date format is slightly off.

Comment: I have to have my date format like that because of oracle db... Its working correctly its just not passing that start and end params scope to only show data for in that range when Im formatting it to PDF for some reason it's not allowing me or im doing something wrong to pass both of those params to my pdf generator @japed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it all out and it was very simple!!! all I had to do was change this..

```
%p= link_to "Printable Report (PDF)", print_version_entry_index_path(@labor_ticket, format: "pdf")
```

To this and presto!!!

```
%p= link_to "Printable Report (PDF)", print_version_entry_index_path(@labor_ticket, format: "pdf", :e => params[:e], :f => params[:f])
```